# "The supervisors can better monitor employees" vs. "supervisors can improve the monitoring of employees"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, sentence, syntactic-analysis, concision

Can we say "the supervisors can better monitor employees" rather than the mouthful that is "supervisors can improve the monitoring of employees"?

Comment: The text should not be translated as it would lead to monitoring of employees

Comment: I can't believe someone created an account just so they could post this comment.  But apparently they did.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the OP's suggestion is that the proposed sentence is ambiguous. 'Supervisors can better monitor employees', could mean that supervisors are better-placed to monitor employees than anyone else. Answer 1 is perhaps clearer but it doesn't altogether remove the ambiguity. Of the three I much prefer the original 'supervisors can improve etc...'

Answer (score 0):

It is slightly difficult commenting out of context but

**"Supervisors can monitor employees better..."**

may work better than "better monitor employees", I am assuming it is followed by a conditional clause.